# CKFinder with external images not on the server

Tags: javascript, php, ckeditor, ckfinder

My application has images hosted on shared third party external server, how to define folder of shared third party image hosting in `filebrowserBrowseUrl` ?
I only have urls of images that are uploaded.

```
CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1', {
    filebrowserBrowseUrl : 'browse.php',
});
```

what should be my logic in browse.php ?

Note:- I only have urls of images not the physical location or directory name.